# Symbol#to_proc shorthand with the stabby lambda syntax

Tags: ruby

Pretty short question: Is it possible to use the Symbol#to_proc shorthand (e.g. `lambda(&:upcase)` with the stabby lambda syntax in Ruby? For example, I can say this:

```
p = lambda &:upcase
```

to get a `Proc` in `p` but I can't find an equivalent using `->`. This:

```
p = -> &:upcase
```

doesn't work, of course.

Comment: My REPL told me I should come here and find Sergio to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is not supported.

I think it has something to do with the fact that [`proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-proc) and [`lambda`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) are actually methods, and not keywords. They support the same features that we usually associate with `each` and the other methods from the [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) module. However, [`->`](http://ruby.about.com/od/newinruby191/qt/LambdaOperator.htm) is a special language construct which is parsed separately.

I can't think of a reason why something like `-> &:method` shouldn't be possible, but as of now the syntax of the Ruby language simply doesn't allow it.

Comment: A minor bummer. Also, it's interesting to note that `proc` or `lambda` with no arguments return `ArgumentError`s while `->` returns a `SyntaxError`.